# How do I use SQL wildcards conditionally?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am trying a query which is not returning the desired results.

```
SELECT [ID], [bookno], [ECN] AS [Version No], [InsertedDate] AS [Add Date]
FROM [BooksBank]
WHERE [Flag] IS NULL AND [bookno] LIKE '%60003-74P00-F%'
AND [ECN] IN 
(SELECT MAX(ECN) FROM [BooksBank]
WHERE [Flag] is NULL AND [bookno] LIKE '%60003-74P00-F%');
```

It is returning the following result

> 75822 | 60003-74P00-F2_511-7434.pdf | 20190527 | 2019-05-28 00:00:00.000

instead of the following which is also the desired result

> 74967 | 60003-74P00-F_55S-0389.pdf | 20190213 | 2019-02-14
>   00:00:00.000

This behavior is technically correct, but I want this result

> 60003-74P00-F_55S-0389.pdf

Please help.

Comment: What is the last condition Supposed to be doing? At present it just reduces your list of matches to a single match with the highest ECN...  *(Removing the `AND ECN IN(SELECT MAX(ECN) FROM blah)` may be the fix you want, but you don't explain why you but it there in the first place.)*

Comment: It is producing the result with the highest ECN which is version or edition. It is a requirement and can't be changed.

Comment: Then you have a problem with your requirement: you want the SINGLE matching record with highest ECN, but you ALSO want to return a second record (which WON'T have the highest ECN).

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. Someone messed up with the naming convention which has resulted into this. The row can't be edited, the max(ecn) can't be dropped - now,a re you saying there's a deadlock and it can't be resolved?

Comment: Your requirement makes no sense. You say you want two records, but only the one with the highest ECN. Do you want two records or one? You can't have it both ways.

Comment: I want one result, the one with the highest ECN. But it should find the highest ECN just for 60003-74P00-F and not for 60003-74P00-F2.

Comment: But the result returned DOES have the highest ECN. Your example data show you're getting `20190527`, but then you say you want the row with `20190213`?  The row you WANT has an ECN that is LOWER than the result you get?

Comment: The result returned DOES have the highest ECN, yes. But it is not confined to 60003-74P00-F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern is too accommodating. You want to match `F_` but not match `F2_`

One way is just to include the `_` in the string you're searching for. *(As `_` is the symbol for "any single character" you do Need to 'escape' it.)*

Change both pattern to...

```
'%60003-74P00-F\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your wildcard search '%60003-74P00-F%' will result in every bookno having "60003-74P00-F" as a sub string.If you want specifically for a particular book you may use = instead of wildcard.

You may try this:

SELECT ID, bookno, InsertedDate AS Add Date,max(ECN) AS Version No, 
FROM BooksBank
WHERE [Flag] IS NULL AND [bookno] = '60003-74P00-F_55S-0389.pdf'
group by ID, bookno, InsertedDate

Comment: Yeah. Except that the users don't know the full name and only know the name before underscore, 60003-74P00-F. That's why I can't go with what you are suggesting.

Comment: Then simply you may use [bookno] LIKE '60003-74P00-F_%'